# ASP.NET CacheDependency not working on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a website running on .NET 3.5 and ASP.NET MVC 2.0. I am using the MvcScriptManager which employs the ASP.NET Cache with a CacheDependency object. The dependency is linked to a file path. When testing locally (Visual Studio 2010), changes to files are detected correctly and the item is removed from the cache, however when deployed to a machine running IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 changes to the file are not detected. Only changing the web.config file or restarting the website will refresh the cache. IIS can read the file, it is just unable to detect changes to it.

Does this have anything to do with a "File Change Notifications" setting? If so, how do I modify that setting?

Is there an additional module I need to install for this to work in integrated mode?

EDIT: I resolved the issue by adjusting the headers that are sent and creating a cache dependency in the System.Web.Caching.Cache class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adjusting the headers that are sent and creating a cache dependency in the System.Web.Caching.Cache class.